# How do you delete a commit in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-commit

I want to completely delete a Mercurial commit as if it was never entered in the repository and move back to my prior commit.

Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338986/is-there-any-way-to-delete-local-commits-in-mercurial - see in particular answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6549478/8479

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to delete local commits in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338986/is-there-any-way-to-delete-local-commits-in-mercurial)

Answer (score 33):

If it was your last commit and you haven't pushed it anywhere, you can do that with `rollback`. Otherwise, no. Not really. Time to change your passwords.

**Edit:** It has been pointed out that you can clone from an older revision and merge in the changes you want to keep. That's also true, unless you have pushed it to a repo you don't control. Once you push, your data is very likely to be very hard to get back.

Comment: haha I have accidentally done that (there goes my ssh private key)

Comment: What about changing the phase to secret if you have not pushed the revision?

Comment: @mikeyUX: This answer was written before 2.1 came out, but changing the phase to secret doesn't actually delete the changeset; it just prevents you from seeing it in `hg outgoing` or sharing it with another repository. Changing the phase to secret, then cloning will do roughly the same thing as my edit suggests. I'd use histedit or mq before doing that though.

Comment: Using the HisteditExtension you can drop a commit. The feature might be newer than this accepted answer.

Comment: @stimpy77: Histedit will still not help if you've pushed or someone has pulled. If neither of those have happened then you're right. Histedit, mq, rollback, and strip will all obliterate changesets if you ask them nicely.

Answer (score 30):

You can try to remove mq info about your commit.

- For this you need to go File->Settings->Extensions.
- There check mq and restart gui.
- After that just right click on unneeded commit and
  ModifyHistory->Strip

Comment: Are you talking about TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 13):

To edit the history I would use the [Histedit Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension.

```
 hg histedit 45:c3a3a271d11c
```

However keep in mind this only makes sense in a situation where you have not yet pushed the commits to the public repository, you own the public repository and/or you can account for all the clones out there. If you receive the following error:

```
abort: can't rebase immutable changeset 43ab8134e7af
```

It means that Mecurial thinks this is a public changeset (see [phases](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/88203)) that has already been pushed - you can force it to be a `draft` again doing:

```
hg phase -f -d 45:c3a3a271d11c
```

Comment: I believe this is the more correct up-to-date answer. Hg evolves.

Answer (score 7):

I encounter this fairly often. I make a commit and *then* pull to push. But then there is something incoming that makes my newly made commit unnecessary. A plain `hg rollback` isn't enough because it only undoes the pull...

This is the thing to do:

```
hg strip <rev>
```

Things are painless when you don't push your changesets anywhere.

Comment: In hg version 6.3.2, i had to use
'hg debugstrip -r <rev>'

Answer (score 6):

If it's more than one commit and/or you already pushed it somewhere else, you can clone your repository and specify the last changeset that should be cloned.

See my answer here how to do this:
[Mercurial: Fix a borked history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310222/mercurial-fix-a-borked-history)

If you only committed locally and didn't push, you can just create a clone locally (as described in my link) and you're done.

If you already pushed to some remote repository, you would have to replace that with your clone.
Of course it depends if you are able (or allowed) to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "hg backout" to do a reverse merge basically.  All options are discussed in the freely available book "Mercurial: The Definitive Guide":

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html

Comment: I realize my suggestion doesn't delete the commit but the link does talk about all options, including the "hg rollback" option nmichaels suggested.

Comment: Generally I like this solution. It's alright to admit your mistakes and keep a history of your bad commits, as well as the fact that you backed them.

Answer (score 3):

If using tortoise you can use modify history > strip...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Unless I am mistaken, as of v2.3 (rel. 2012/08/01) you can use the HisteditExtension  **with a `drop`** command to drop a commit, along with `strip` or `backout` to remove changes.

A simple Google search on the feature: https://www.google.com/webhp#q=histedit+drop

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 I do use [`evolve`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#life-with-evolve-basic-usage) extension.  It is one of the best extensions for this purpose.

To `prune` unwanted changeset, if you for example did a quick hack to get the code working:

```
$ echo 'debug hack' >> file1.c
$ hg commit -m 'debug hack'
```

Now you have a proper patch you can do `hg prune .`:

```
$ hg prune .
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
working directory is now at 2a39221aaebb
1 changesets pruned
```

If you push the change to the remote repository you will find only `obsolescence` markers:

```
$ hg push
searching for changes                          
no changes found                               
remote: 1 new obsolescence markers
```

To check the changes to your local repo you can `pull` from the remote one:

```
$ hg pull                            
pulling from ssh://userid@server/repo
searching for changes      
no changes found
```